# Is there dependency between Unix/Linux IPC facilities?

Tags: linux, synchronization, ipc, api

*The Linux Programming Interface* summarizes UNIX/Linux IPC facilities for communication and synchronization

> [image]

Is there dependency between any of the facilities? Either between their interfaces or their (typical) implementations, for example:

- At interface level: Using POSIX shared memory relies on  using memory mapping, if I remember correctly. Is there any other case?
- At implementation level: RPC (not part of Unix/Linux IPC facilities) is implemented on top of network sockets. Does implementation dependency exist between Unix/Linux IPC facilities?

My guess is that Unix/Linux IPC facilities are largely independent of each other both at their interfaces and in their implementations. If that is true, it is very different from the IPC facilities between processes on different computers over a network or internet, which are often implemented on one another (commonly, on sockets and HTTP), while maintain independence at their interfaces. I am trying to transfer knowledge between those two cases and also note their differences.

Thanks.

Comment: I think there is something about semaphores and shared memory. Mentioned here https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html

Comment: Thanks. I see. Semaphores have to be put in shared memory to be shared between processes.